# Reading garbage instead of segfault for non-existant memory locations

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, out-of-memory

I was trying to define an array in c++

```
double array[592];
```

I made a mistake and used "sizeof" command instead of size to limit a loop which printed the elements one by one. Hence, the loop was reading array indices until index 4736. Although these locations do not exist, I was getting garbage instead of segmentation fault for all locations after 592. I'm wondering why I'm not getting segmentation fault.

Comment: sizeof is the size in bytes...

Comment: You could at least read [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof) first.

Comment: Try printing `sizeof(double)`. And then do `sizeof(array) / sizeof(double)`.

Comment: Is google down again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sizeof` gives you the number of bytes the array occupies, not the number of elements it consists of. So as a `double` requires 8 bytes on your system, the result should become clear.

Answer (score 0):

```
sizeof(array) // Returns 592 * sizeof(double)
```

Gives you the total number of bytes occupied by an array.